# How to separate character and number part from string

Tags: c#, string

E.g., I would like to separate:

- `OS234` to `OS` and `234`
- `AA4230` to `AA` and `4230`

I have used following trivial solution, but I am quite sure that there should be a more efficient and robust solution .

```
private void demo()
    {   string cell="ABCD4321";
        int a = getIndexofNumber(cell);
        string Numberpart = cell.Substring(a, cell.Length - a);
        row = Convert.ToInt32(rowpart);
        string Stringpart = cell.Substring(0, a);
    }

private int getIndexofNumber(string cell)
        {
            int a = -1, indexofNum = 10000;
            a = cell.IndexOf("0"); if (a > -1) { if (indexofNum > a) { indexofNum = a; } }
            a = cell.IndexOf("1"); if (a > -1) { if (indexofNum > a) { indexofNum = a; } }
            a = cell.IndexOf("2"); if (a > -1) { if (indexofNum > a) { indexofNum = a; } }
            a = cell.IndexOf("3"); if (a > -1) { if (indexofNum > a) { indexofNum = a; } }
            a = cell.IndexOf("4"); if (a > -1) { if (indexofNum > a) { indexofNum = a; } }
            a = cell.IndexOf("5"); if (a > -1) { if (indexofNum > a) { indexofNum = a; } }
            a = cell.IndexOf("6"); if (a > -1) { if (indexofNum > a) { indexofNum = a; } }
            a = cell.IndexOf("7"); if (a > -1) { if (indexofNum > a) { indexofNum = a; } }
            a = cell.IndexOf("8"); if (a > -1) { if (indexofNum > a) { indexofNum = a; } }
            a = cell.IndexOf("9"); if (a > -1) { if (indexofNum > a) { indexofNum = a; } }

            if (indexofNum != 10000)
            { return indexofNum; }
            else
            { return 0; }


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used bniwredyc's answer to get Improved version of my routine:

```
    private void demo()
        {
            string cell = "ABCD4321";
            int row, a = getIndexofNumber(cell);
            string Numberpart = cell.Substring(a, cell.Length - a);
            row = Convert.ToInt32(Numberpart);
            string Stringpart = cell.Substring(0, a);
        }

        private int getIndexofNumber(string cell)
        {
            int indexofNum=-1;
            foreach (char c in cell)
            {
                indexofNum++;
                if (Char.IsDigit(c))
                {
                    return indexofNum;
                }
             }
            return indexofNum;
        }
```

Answer (score 36):

Regular Expressions are best suited for this kind of work:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex re = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)");
Match result = re.Match(input);

string alphaPart = result.Groups[1].Value;
string numberPart = result.Groups[2].Value;
```

Comment: Might want to add two lines to this answer:

    string alphaPart = result.Groups[1];
    string numberPart = result.Groups[2];

Comment: Following seems to be more complete solution:
  Regex re = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)");
            Match result = re.Match("as23");
            string alphaPart = result.Groups[1].ToString ();
            string numberPart = result.Groups[2].ToString();

Comment: Isn't it `result.Groups[1].Value`?

Comment: result.Groups[2].ToString(); Worked for me
Further we should add Imports Systems.Text.Regularexpression @ top.

Comment: "GJ10HE1895" is my string any i want it like GJ,10,HE, 1895 seperately in different group can you suggest solution. @x0n

Answer (score 13):

Use Linq to do this

```
string str = "OS234";

var digits = from c in str
             select c
             where Char.IsDigit(c);

var alphas = from c in str
             select c
             where !Char.IsDigit(c);
```

Comment: This seems to be good solution ,but unfortunately .net 2.0 users  could not use Linq

Comment: I recomend - upgrade to C# 3.0.

Answer (score 6):

Everyone and their mother will give you a solution using regex, so here's one that is not:

```
 // s is string of form ([A-Za-z])*([0-9])* ; char added
 int index = s.IndexOfAny(new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' });
 string chars = s.Substring(0, index);
 int num = Int32.Parse(s.Substring(index));
```

Comment: You got regex problems? I feel bad for you son. I got 99 problems but a Regex ain't one.

Answer (score 6):

I really like [jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1968064/1248177). Lets improve it a bit. We dont need regex here. My solution handle input like "H1N1":

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitAlpha(string input)
{
    var words = new List<string> { string.Empty };
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        words[words.Count-1] += input[i];
        if (i + 1 < input.Length && char.IsLetter(input[i]) != char.IsLetter(input[i + 1]))
        {
            words.Add(string.Empty);
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

This solution is linear O(n).

output

```
"H1N1" -> ["H", "1", "N", "1"]
"H" -> ["H"]
"GH1N12" -> ["GH", "1", "N", "12"]
"OS234" -> ["OS", "234"]
```

Same solution with a `StringBuilder`

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitAlpha(string input)
{
    var words = new List<StringBuilder>{new StringBuilder()};
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {
        words[words.Count - 1].Append(input[i]);
        if (i + 1 < input.Length && char.IsLetter(input[i]) != char.IsLetter(input[i + 1]))
        {
            words.Add(new StringBuilder());
        }
    }

    return words.Select(x => x.ToString());
}
```

[Try it Online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p4ty8c)

Comment: I needed this. Thanks

Comment: @DJBurb Glad I could be useful :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want resolve more occurrences of char followed by number or vice versa you can use

```
private string SplitCharsAndNums(string text)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 0; i < text.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if ((char.IsLetter(text[i]) && char.IsDigit(text[i+1])) ||
            (char.IsDigit(text[i]) && char.IsLetter(text[i+1])))
        {
            sb.Append(text[i]);
            sb.Append(" ");
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(text[i]);
        }
    }

    sb.Append(text[text.Length-1]);

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And then

```
var text = SplitCharsAndNums("asd1 asas4gr5 6ssfd");
var tokens = text.Split(' ');
```

Comment: Works well until you meet a non-letter or numeric, such as a . in a file name. Change char.IsLetter to !char.IsNumeric

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this for sorting purposes?  If so, keep in mind that Regex can kill performance for large lists.  I frequently use an `AlphanumComparer` that's a general solution to this problem (can handle any sequence of letters and numbers in any order).  I believe that I adapted it from [this page](http://dotnetperls.com/alphanumeric-sorting).

Even if you're not sorting on it, using the character-by-character approach (if you have variable lengths) or simple substring/parse (if they're fixed) will be a lot more efficient and easier to test than a Regex.

Answer (score 1):

.NET 2.0 compatible, without regex

```
public class Result
{
    private string _StringPart;
    public string StringPart
    {
        get { return _StringPart; }
    }

    private int _IntPart;
    public int IntPart
    {
        get { return _IntPart; }
    }

    public Result(string stringPart, int intPart)
    {
        _StringPart = stringPart;
        _IntPart = intPart;
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static Result GetResult(string source)
    {
        string stringPart = String.Empty;
        int intPart;
        var buffer = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char c in source)
        {
            if (Char.IsDigit(c))
            {
               if (stringPart == String.Empty)
               {
                    stringPart = buffer.ToString();
                    buffer.Remove(0, buffer.Length);
                }
            }

            buffer.Append(c);
        }

        if (!int.TryParse(buffer.ToString(), out intPart))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return new Result(stringPart, intPart); 
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Result result = GetResult("OS234");
        Console.WriteLine("String part: {0} int part: {1}", result.StringPart, result.IntPart);
        result = GetResult("AA4230 ");
        Console.WriteLine("String part: {0} int part: {1}", result.StringPart, result.IntPart);
        result = GetResult("ABCD4321");
        Console.WriteLine("String part: {0} int part: {1}", result.StringPart, result.IntPart);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: @this.__curious_geek yep. I like Jasons solution.

Answer (score -2):

Just use the `substring` function and set position inside the bracket.

```
 String id = "DON123";
 System.out.println("Id nubmer is : "+id.substring(3,6));
```

Answer:

```
 Id number is: 123
```

Comment: The string is not the same length each time, nor the number of characters or digits

Answer (score -3):

use Split to seprate string from sting that use tab \t and space

```
string s = "sometext\tsometext\tsometext";
string[] split = s.Split('\t');
```

now you have an array of string that you want too easy

Comment: this answer is irrelevant to the question, it's not about separating number from letters at all. also your "too easy" in the end sounds spiteful, author wouldn't ask question if that was as easy as this answer states