# SQL Server 2008 - order by strings with number numerically

Tags: sql-server

I have following values in my table:

```
ABC
ABC1
ABC2
ABC3 and so on...

ABC11
ABC12
ABC13 and so on..

ABC20
ABC21
ABC22 and so on..
```

So basically what I have is any string value (not always ABC, any string value) that can either be followed by the number or it may just be a string without the number.

When I do select * from table order by my column asc I get following results:

```
ABC
ABC1
ABC11
ABC12
ABC13
ABC2
ABC20
ABC21
ABC22
ABC3
ABC31
ABC32
```

I need it sorted numerically:

```
ABC
ABC1
ABC2
ABC3
ABC11
ABC12
ABC13
ABC20
ABC21
ABC22
ABC31
ABC32
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Any idea how many characters at the end can be numerics?

Comment: And where does AB1 fit versus ABC1? Before or After? - Best bet, I'd say is to maintain a sorting column to avoid sorting on stuff like that.Because you can quickly end up with quite a complex order by which will slow your query way down.

Comment: So `ABC` can actually be any string with any length? Can it also contain numeric characters, e.g. `A1B2C1234`? If so, how do you want to sort that?

Answer (score 21):

*(based on answers from [@shenhengbin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/804289/shenhengbin) and [@EchO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4977408/echo) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6396378/3258851))*

The following is what I call a "clean hack". Assuming you are ordering on column `Col1`:

```
ORDER BY LEN(Col1), Col1
```

It is a hack, although I'd personally feel proud using it.

Comment: really smart hack - I feel honoured to be able to use it ;-)

Comment: God bless you, dear friend!)

Answer (score 17):

You can do it using PATINDEX() function like below :

```
select * from Test 
order by CAST(SUBSTRING(Name + '0', PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Name + '0'), LEN(Name + '0')) AS INT)
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/79a34a/2)**

If you have numbers in middle of the string then you need to create small user defined function to get number from string and sort data based on that number like below :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnGetNumberFromString (@strInput VARCHAR(255)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(255) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @intNumber int 
    SET @intNumber = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strInput)

    WHILE @intNumber > 0
    BEGIN 
        SET @strInput = STUFF(@strInput, @intNumber, 1, '')
        SET @intNumber = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strInput)
    END 

    RETURN ISNULL(@strInput,0) 
END 
GO
```

You can sort data by :

```
select Name from Test order by dbo.fnGetNumberFromString(Name), Name
```

Comment: Oooh, nice one, +1! Works fine as long as the string part comes first and the number part comes last.

Comment: This would work great if all my values were in the format: stringnumber, however I have some values such as AD2_NDU, ECOS_10_CHANGEOFSTATUS, etc. and the solution above errors out for these values...is there something that can be addedd to only apply this format to string that ends with numbers?

Comment: If there is no. in between string then how should it sort ? i.e. which will come first in these nos ? "AD2_NDU" or "ABC" or "ABC1" or "ABC2"

Comment: well, I get no errors but it is not sorting it correctly... I get values that start with 'B' or 'C' before those that start with 'A'.

Comment: Results with using the function:

Comment: BECLAIMS
CDB
CIW_ASC
CIW_BCS
CIW_NCSC
CLAIMS
AGNT_DOC
APFORMS
ASCBilling
AUTH_FORM
AD_NDU
CMSOPTO
CMSPGBA
COBMI
COBNONMI
COVERSHEET
CUST_INQ
CUST_INQUIRY
DANFTPTEST
DBILLMBR
ENRLBILL
ENROLL_UNDER
EPIP
FAC_ROSTER
FECLAIMS
FIELD_UNDER
FILE_MT
FIN_RPT
GRIEV_AP
MANON837
CIW9
STATUS_90
CMS_9200
STATUS_93
STATUS_95
STATUS_98
CIW99
CIW999

Comment: My desired result should be AD_NDU
AD2_NDU
ADA2006
AGNT_DOC
APFORMS
ASCBilling
AUTH_FORM
AUTH_FORM2
BC_U600
BECLAIMS
CDB
CIW_ASC
CIW_BCS
CIW_NCSC
CIW1
CIW2
CIW3 and so on...

Comment: You can sort result on name after function value as I have done in my updated answer. Check it

Comment: it is still not sorting correctly =(
AD_NDU
AGNT_DOC
APFORMS
ASCBilling
AUTH_FORM
BECLAIMS
CDB
CIW_ASC
CIW_BCS
CIW_NCSC
CLAIMS
CUST_INQ4
DBILLMBR4
MCAIDUB4
CMS_405
CIW41
CMS_410
CMS_412
CIW48
CIW49
CIW5
CUST_INQ5
DBILLMBR5
CIW50
DENTAL_500
BC_U600
CIW61
CIW62
CIW63
CIW64
CIW65
CIW66
CIW7
CIW8

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42166/discussion-between-upendra-chaudhari-and-user2179092)

Comment: Still I can't understand what you want actually, if you want to sort data based on nos and then alphabets, you just keep function followed by name in order by clause, if you want to give priority on alphabet first then change the order of columns in order by clause, that's it simple.

Comment: Very nice.  A variant, which I am using for sorting identifiers that start with a string of digits and may optionally have suffixed a hypen and digit, or one or more characters, or one or more characters followed by a hyphen and digit (how do I format a comment??)   `select * from @work2
order by CAST(SUBSTRING('0'+ unitcode, 0, PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z\-]%', '0'+unitcode)) AS INT), 
 SUBSTRING('0'+ unitcode, PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z\-]%', '0'+ unitcode), LEN('0'+ unitcode))`

Comment: OK, a correction after some debugging:    `select  * 
from @temptable
    order by  case when patindex('%[A-Za-z\-]%', '0'+unitcode) > 0 then CAST(SUBSTRING('0'+ unitcode, 0, PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z\-]%', '0'+unitcode)) AS INT)
      else CAST('0' + unitcode AS INT)
    end, 
    case when patindex('%[A-Za-z\-]%', '0'+unitcode) > 0 then SUBSTRING('0'+ unitcode, PATINDEX('%[A-Za-z\-]%', '0'+ unitcode), LEN('0'+ unitcode))
      else ''
    end`

Answer (score 7):

In order by statement, prepend enough zeros with when value contains any number in it to make all alphanumerica value same length

```
SELECT ColName
FROM TableName
ORDER BY 
 CASE WHEN ColName like '%[0-9]%' 
 THEN Replicate('0', 100 - Len(ColName)) + ColName
 ELSE ColName  END
```

Answer (score 5):

You could remove the first three characters and cast the rest to `int`

```
SELECT Value,
       Num=CAST(RIGHT(Value, LEN(Value) - 3) AS int)
FROM dbo.TableName
ORDER BY Num
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b0023/8/0)</kbd>

Comment: Nice solution, if the string always has length 3 - wording in the question seems to suggest that's not the case though...

Comment: It will work only for fix 3 character string, it will not work for string like "ABCD11"

Comment: @UpendraChaudhari: Yes, that's what Josien has already mentioned. I have overlooked the part that the string is arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

You could adapt the function *RemoveNonAlphaCharacters* in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008566/249353) to filter out everything except numbers, and then use an `ORDER BY` using that function.

Answer (score 1):

Using Standard SQL ONLY this query demonstrates how you can ODER BY either the numbers found to be contained at the Beginning or the End of the string.  The query also shows how you could then look at the remaining 'inner' portion of the string to see if there are any numbers contained there.  Knowing if there are numbers contained within the string could be useful if further processing is necessary.

```
WITH stringNumberData AS
(   /* Build up Fake data with Numbers at the Beginning, End and Middle of the string */
    SELECT 1  AS uniqueKey, 'ABC'      AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 2  AS uniqueKey, 'ABC1'     AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 3  AS uniqueKey, 'ABC2'     AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 4  AS uniqueKey, 'ABC3'     AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 5  AS uniqueKey, 'ABC10'    AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 6  AS uniqueKey, 'ABC11'    AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 7  AS uniqueKey, 'ABC12'    AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 8  AS uniqueKey, 'ABC20'    AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 9  AS uniqueKey, 'ABC21'    AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 AS uniqueKey, 'ABC22'    AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 11 AS uniqueKey, 'ABC30'    AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 12 AS uniqueKey, 'ABC31'    AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 13 AS uniqueKey, 'ABC32'    AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 14 AS uniqueKey, '1ABC'     AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 15 AS uniqueKey, '2ABC'     AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 16 AS uniqueKey, '3ABC'     AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 17 AS uniqueKey, '10ABC'    AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 18 AS uniqueKey, '11BC'     AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 19 AS uniqueKey, '12ABC'    AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 20 AS uniqueKey, '10ABC18'  AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 21 AS uniqueKey, '11BC52'   AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 22 AS uniqueKey, '12ABC42'  AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 23 AS uniqueKey, 'A3BC18'   AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 24 AS uniqueKey, 'B3C52'    AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 25 AS uniqueKey, '12AB3C'   AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 26 AS uniqueKey, 'A3BC'     AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 27 AS uniqueKey, 'AB2C'     AS NumberFromString UNION ALL
    SELECT 28 AS uniqueKey, 'ABC85D'   AS NumberFromString

)   

SELECT d.uniqueKey, d.NumberFromString
    /* Extract numerical values contained on the LEFT of the String by finding the index of the first non number */
    , LEFT(d.NumberFromString, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', d.NumberFromString) -1) AS 'Left Numbers Extraction'

    /* Extract numerical data contained on the RIGHT of the String */
    , RIGHT(d.NumberFromString, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(d.NumberFromString)) - 1 ) AS 'Right Numbers Extraction'

    /* The below checks inside the Inner string to determine if numbers exists within it.  Could be used for further processing if further extraction is necessary */
    , PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',
        SUBSTRING(d.NumberFromString /*, Start Pos, Length to Extract) */
            , PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', d.NumberFromString)  /* Start Pos is first left non number */
            /* The below obtains the length of the Inner String so it can be extracted */
            , LEN(d.NumberFromString) - ((PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', d.NumberFromString) -1 )) -  (PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(d.NumberFromString)) -1) /* (String Length) - (LEFT Numbers) - (RIGHT Numbers) */
      )) AS innerNumExists

    /* The two lines below tell us if there exists a number at the Beginning and/or End of the string */
    , PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',  LEFT(d.NumberFromString, 1)) AS leftNumExists
    , PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', RIGHT(d.NumberFromString, 1)) AS rightNumExists

    /* Locates and returns the index of the very first number located in the string from Left to Right */
    , PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', d.NumberFromString) AS firstLeftNonNum_index

    /* Locates and returns the index of the very first number located in the string from Right to Left */
    , LEN(d.NumberFromString) - (PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(d.NumberFromString)) -1 ) AS firstRightNonNum_index

    /* Get the length of the numbers existing from Right to Left up to the first non numeric character */   
    , PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(d.NumberFromString)) -1 AS rightStringLen


FROM stringNumberData d
ORDER BY 
    /* Ordering first by numbers found on the LEFT of the string */
    CAST(LEFT(d.NumberFromString, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', d.NumberFromString) -1) AS INT )
    /* Ordering second by numbers found on the RIGHT of the string */
    , CAST(RIGHT(d.NumberFromString, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', REVERSE(d.NumberFromString)) - 1 ) AS INT )
;
```

[image: Query Results]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple to understand example for those using SQL Server 17+.

```
DECLARE @Data table ( val varchar(10) );
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES
    ( 'ABC' ),( 'ABC1' ),( 'ABC11' ),( 'ABC12' ),( 'ABC13' ),( 'ABC2' ), ( 'B1C' ),
    ( 'ABC20' ),( 'ABC21' ),( 'ABC22' ),( 'ABC3' ),( 'ABC31' ),( 'ABC32' );

SELECT val FROM @Data AS d
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CAST ( TRANSLATE ( d.val, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', '                          ' ) AS int ) AS Num
) AS x
ORDER BY
    LEFT ( val, 1 ), Num;
```

Returns

```
+-------+
|  val  |
+-------+
| ABC   |
| ABC1  |
| ABC2  |
| ABC3  |
| ABC11 |
| ABC12 |
| ABC13 |
| ABC20 |
| ABC21 |
| ABC22 |
| ABC31 |
| ABC32 |
| B1C   |
+-------+
```

SQL Server's TRANSLATE takes three parameters: `inputString, characters, translations`.

The `inputString` in your case is your column name.

The `characters` are the values you're looking to replace, in this case the alphabet.

The `translations` are the values to replace with. This string must be equal in length to the `characters`--hence the empty string that's 26 spaces long.

And finally, using `CAST` ignores the spaces and allows the remaining value to be sorted as an int.

You can read about TRANSLATE here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15