# Data Ordering & Select Max SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let say I have a `user` table and the record is like this:

```
----------------------
| User ID | Username |
----------------------
|US1      | Andy     |
|US2      | Boston   |
|US3      | Charlie  |
|US4      | Donnie   |
|US5      | Elmo     |
|US6      | Frank    |
|US7      | Garry    |
|US8      | Henry    |
|US9      | Ignatius |
|US10     | John     |
```

What I need is

```
US10      | John
```

Then I do:

```
SELECT MAX (UserId) FROM User;
```

The result was

```
US9      | Ignatius
```

because its ordered by string literally, so US10 is not the max

What should I do to accomplished that result?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: keep in mind that `user` is a reserved word in sql so it should be used by brackets around that `[user]`

There are many options:

1)

```
select top 1 Userid,
CAST(SUBSTRING(UserId, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', UserId), LEN(UserId)) AS INT) as Maxid,
username
from [user] 
Order By Maxid desc
```

Output:

```
Userid  Maxid   username
=============================
US10    10      John
```

2)

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [User]
ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(UserId,LEN(UserId)-2) AS INT) DESC
```

Output

```
userid  username
=====================
US10    John
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have fixed format for data like numbers are at last in string then you can use PATINDEX() function to get number from string like

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [User]
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(UserId, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', UserId), LEN(UserId)) AS INT) DESC;
```

**If you have not fixed format for number in string and you want to sort data based on numbers only then check more details in below link**

**[SQL Server 2008 - order by strings with number numerically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240313/sql-server-2008-order-by-strings-with-number-numerically/20240619#20240619)**

Comment: `user` is a reserved word in sql so it should be used by brackets around that `[user]`

Comment: yes, I know, it was just for example, still I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your column format always have the same quantity of character at the beginning, you can use this query to remove the first 2 characters and convert the remaining to number in order the get the proper behaviour on your max query :

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(`UserId` FROM 3) AS UNSIGNED)) FROM `User` ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM User ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(UserId,LEN(UserId)-2) AS INT) DESC
```

OP

> US10   | John