# T-SQL Not staying in order

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a database in SQL Server console C# where there are different groups added to a row vertically, eg G1, G2, G3 etc.

This is ok for what is needed, however when a value is added like so G10, it automatically put itself under G1, so instead of

```
G1
G2
G3
G10
```

it looks like this:

```
G1
G10
G2
G3
```

I have tried the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM mondayTable 
ORDER BY SAAT ASC
```

and

```
ORDER BY SAAT DESC
```

but it still stays in the same order, but from top to bottom, bottom to top.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like with `ORDER BY DESC`:

[image]

Comment: is the format of `SAAT` column fixed?i.e an alphabet followed by a number?

Comment: This is because the SAAT column is alphabetic, so the sort is alphabetic not numerical.

Comment: Since there are `G` characters in the column, it must be of datatype `varchar` presumably - and as a **string**, it's ordered **correctly**.

Comment: hey guys, sorry I should have mentioned that `SAAT` set to `varchar(50)`

Comment: Literally first answer when i googled how to sort alphanumeric values in sql server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240313/sql-server-2008-order-by-strings-with-number-numerically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commenters pointed out it's because your data is alphabetic so the sort is correct.  You could use something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mondayTable 
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(SAAT,2,LEN(SAAT)) AS INT)
```

Comment: Wow! how about that! Thanks Squillman for helping out :) I don't to annoy you however, could you explain for me how your answer works? I don't want to be a control c control v junkie :)

Comment: @Werdna The ORDER BY strips off the numeric characters and casts them as an integer value.  Since the integer value is numeric it provides the sort you are looking for.  This does assume a single character in the string value at the beginning and that the numeric characters start at position 2.

Comment: Thank you Squillman for explaining that I understand now, Thank you again, I hope you have a good weekend :)

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior because you are sorting on characters.  To place it in order I would pad the numbers after the "G".

For example:

G01
G02
G03
G04
G05
G06
G07
G08
G09
G10
G11

OR if you think the numbers will go into the 1000's

G0001
G0002
G0003
G0004
G0005
G0006
G0007
G0008
G0009
G0010
G0011

an easy way to pad is

SELECT 'G'+ RIGHT('000'+CAST(2 as varchar(4)),4)

SELECT 'G'+ RIGHT('000'+CAST(11 as varchar(4)),4)

This will generate

G0002
G0011

Another way could be to do order by like this

ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(SAAT,'G','') AS INT) ASC