# SQL Sort of mixed numbers and alphanumeric Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-order-by

I'm going to sort that column contains the value of numbers and alphanumeric value.

But I got the wrong sort (`order by`) can anyone help me regarding with this problem?

I'm using **SQL SERVER 2008 R2**, here's the sample:

```
DECLARE @TableTester TABLE (TESTER VARCHAR(50));

INSERT @TableTester VALUES
('1'),
('2'),
('3'),
('4'),
('10'),
('20'),
('5 ; 6'),
('122'),
('256 ; 78'),
('U1 ; U2'),
('U3 ; 7'),
('C1'),
('U4'),
('WC23'),
('WC214 ; U4'),
('U10');

SELECT Tester FROM @TableTester
ORDER BY CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Tester) > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, 
CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Tester) > 0 
THEN LEFT(Tester, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', Tester)-1) ELSE Tester END
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
1
2
3
4
10
20
5 ; 6
122
256 ; 78
C1
U4
U10
U1 ; U2
U3 ; 7
WC23
WC214 ; U4
```

**DESIRED RESULT:**

```
1
2
3
4
5 ; 6
10
20
122
256 ; 78
C1
U1 ; U2
U3 ; 7
U4
U10
WC23
WC214 ; U4
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 - order by strings with number numerically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240313/sql-server-2008-order-by-strings-with-number-numerically)

Comment: Also, if the answers to the duplicate question are hard to follow, there is this: http://www.essentialsql.com/use-sql-server-to-sort-alphanumeric-values/

Comment: @hatchet , but I have multiple values in my column that separated semicolon ";"

Comment: You seem to be saying that question is not a duplicate because it doesn't handle the semicolon issue present in your case. So I'll retract my close vote. Unfortunately, I don't have SQL Server handy right now, so can't try out a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, normalize your data - this ordering is weird:

```
SELECT TESTER 
FROM @TableTester
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN TESTER LIKE '[A-Z]%' THEN LEFT(TESTER,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',TESTER)-1) ELSE NULL END,
    CAST(
        CASE WHEN TESTER LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
                THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(TESTER,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',TESTER),CHARINDEX(' ;',TESTER+' ;')-1),' ;','') 
                ELSE TESTER END
                        as int)
```

The main idea is to get letters and digits separated and than use cast to make them integer and sort first by letters than by integer.