# Check if a string is sorted

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, sorting

I have a string, simplified `"12345"` which is sorted. The string couild contain Digits (0-9) or letters (a-z). In case of a mixed use the natural sort order. I need a method to verify if this is true.

Attempt with linq technique:

```
string items1 = "2349"; //sorted
string items2 = "2476"; //not sorted, 6<>7

bool sorted1 = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(items1.OrderBy(x => x), items1); //true
bool sorted2 = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(items2.OrderBy(x => x), items2); //false
```

but there could be also a descending sort order.

Is there a better way then

```
string items3 = "4321";
bool sorted3 = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(items3.OrderBy(x => x), items3) || Enumerable.SequenceEqual(items3.OrderByDescending(x => x), items3);
```

to check if a string is sorted? Maybe some built in solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396378/c-sharp-linq-orderby-numbers-that-are-string-and-you-cannot-convert-them-to-int

Comment: What if the string contains letters ? You've just showed us the best case scenario. What if the characters are not English alphabets ( eg `-` or `?`) ?

Comment: @c0rd So `123abc` and `abc123` and `ab12cd34` are considered sorted ?

Comment: @user3185569 "123abc" or "cba321" are valid

Comment: Please define "better". Is it "faster" or "more readable" or "consume less memory"?

Comment: Would `123abc` be ok? What about `1a2b3c`? What do you mean by "natural sort order"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once had to check something similar to your case but with huge data streams, so performance was important. I came up with this small extension class which performs very well:

```
public static bool IsOrdered<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) where T: IComparable<T>
{
    using (var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            return true; //empty enumeration is ordered

        var left = enumerator.Current;
        int previousUnequalComparison = 0;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var right = enumerator.Current;
            var currentComparison = left.CompareTo(right);

            if (currentComparison != 0)
            {
                if (previousUnequalComparison != 0
                    && currentComparison != previousUnequalComparison)
                    return false;

                previousUnequalComparison = currentComparison;
                left = right;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Using it is obviously very simple:

```
var items1 = "2349";
var items2 = "2476"; //not sorted, 6<>7
items1.IsOrdered(); //true
items2.IsOrdered(); //false
```

Comment: This is indeed the right way. Much better than any of the "concise" pure LINQ attempts. DRY and the **usage** is much more concise and readable.

Answer (score 6):

Your solution in fine and very readable. One problem with it is that it requires ordering the `string` [which is ***O(n * log(n))***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm), this can be solved by iterating the `string` without sorting it.

For example:

```
var firstDifs = items1.Zip(items1.Skip(1), (x, y) => y - x);
```

This `Linq` projects every 2 items in the first `string` to a number which indicates their difference, So if you have `items1 = "1245"` the output will be:

> firstDifs: `{1, 2, 1}`

Now all you need to do is to validate that `firstDifs` is either ascending or descending:

```
bool firstSorted = firstDifs.All(x => x > 0) || firstDifs.All(x => x < 0); //true
```

Now:

- [`Skip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx) is ***O(1)*** since the amount of actions required to skip 1 cell is 
  constant.
- [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) is ***O(n)***.
- [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) is ***O(n)***.

So the whole solution is ***O(n)***.

Note that ***it will be more efficient with a simple loop***, also if the first [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) has returned `false` because the 3487th item changes its direction (for example: 1234567891), the second [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) will run for no reason with the [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) running twice as well <sub>(Until where [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) require)</sub> - since there are two iterations of [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx) and `Linq` evaluates them lazily.

Comment: Are you sure about iterating multiple times? Isn't it so that ZIP only iterates through the really needed elements, so if I find at the third iteration of the ALL that the result is false, and thus the rest of ALL is not iterated, that the rest is also not zipped?

Comment: @HaraldDutch The zipping will be done twice since there are two iterations of `All` and `Linq` evaluates them lazily.

Comment: @TamirVered `All()` stops processing if one invalid character was found so ist up to **O(n)** right?

Comment: @c0rd if you have any repeating characters, change to `x >= 0` and `x <= 0`

Answer (score 3):

It requires a [reducer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29). In C#, it's [Enumerable.Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx). It's O(n) algorithm.

```
var query = "123abc".Aggregate(new { asceding = true, descending = true, prev = (char?)null }, 
(result, currentChar) =>
    new 
    { 
       asceding = result.prev == null || result.asceding && currentChar >= result.prev, 
       descending = result.prev == null || result.descending && currentChar <= result.prev, 
       prev = (char?)currentChar 
    }
);
Console.WriteLine(query.asceding || query.descending );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do much better than the accepted answer by not having to compare all of the elements:

```
var s = "2349"; 
var r = Enumerable.Range(1, s.Length - 1);
//var isAscending = r.All(i => s[i - 1] <= s[i]);
//var isDescending = r.All(i => s[i - 1] >= s[i]);
var isOrdered = r.All(i => s[i - 1] <= s[i]) || r.All(i => s[i - 1] >= s[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = "4321";
var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(i => i); // Process the order once only
var sorted = sortedItems.SequenceEqual(items) || sortedItems.SequenceEqual(items.Reverse()); // Reverse using yield return
```

Comment: the result of `OrderBy` is a IEnumberable which should be processed every call

Answer (score 0):

I would go for simple iteration over all elements:

```
string str = "whatever123";
Func<char, char, bool> pred;
bool? asc = str.TakeWhile((q, i) => i < str.Length - 1)
               .Select((q, i) => str[i] == str[i+1] ? (bool?)null : str[i] < str[i+1])
               .FirstOrDefault(q => q.HasValue);
if (!asc.HasValue)
    return true; //all chars are the same
if (asc.Value)
    pred = (c1, c2) => c1 <= c2;
else
    pred = (c1, c2) => c1 >= c2;

for (int i = 0; i < str.Length - 1; ++i)
{
    if (!pred(str[i], str[i + 1]))
        return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: __Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'char'__

Comment: I always get the `Func` declaration wrong, I changed it, please try now

Comment: ok works now but returns `"aabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` false

Comment: this is because of the commented TODO

Comment: @c0rd fixed it for you as well