# Linq orderby OrderByDescending not working when there's more than 2 digits c#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am using OrderByDescending and it works great, except that when I add numbers that are more than 3 digits they get messed up. for example:

```
List<int> = {20, 84, 102, 94, 205, 33}
```

it will order it like this:

```
94, 84, 33, 205, 20, 102
```

It's as if there were decimals instead of whole numbers. How can I fix this issue? and make it descend from greatest value to least value

Comment: Please post your  entire *actual* code.

Comment: That result can come as the result of sorting *numerals* (strings).  Show the code which gives that result using integers

Comment: Pending the question being updated with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that actually compiles, possible duplicate of [LINQ OrderBy or Sort does not order correctly for integer string list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942428/linq-orderby-or-sort-does-not-order-correctly-for-integer-string-list).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ OrderBy or Sort does not order correctly for integer string list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40942428/linq-orderby-or-sort-does-not-order-correctly-for-integer-string-list)

Answer (score 4):

Based on your sorting results, it appears that you're actually sorting a `List<string>`, not a `List<int>`.

If you're sure all the elements in the list are valid integers, you can use `int.Parse` to convert them on the fly in your `OrderByDescending` clause:

```
var numbers = new List<string> {"20", "84", "102", "94", "205", "33"};

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", numbers.OrderByDescending(int.Parse)));
```

**Output**

[image]