# c# Order numbers in ComboBox that are string using Linq (ObservableCollection)

Tags: c#, linq, mvvm, combobox, observablecollection

I am using MVVM and I want to sort my `ComboBox` by ascending numbers.
My items (from database) stored in an `ObservableCollection` are always numbers stored as string.

Once I go past 10 my `ComboBox` shows `1` followed by `10`.

Can I adjust the Linq to sort correctly?

Or am I trying it wrong?

```
public ObservableCollection<clsItemsModel> MyCollection
{
    get { return _MyCollection; }
    set
    {
        _MyCollection = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

private void LoadData()
{
    MyCollection = _clsItemsDataService.GetItems();
    MyCollection.OrderBy(p => p.Items);
}
```

Comment: You have to convert the strings to ints before sorting if you want, for instance, 1 3 9 10 instead of 1 10 3 9.

Comment: `int.Parse(p.Items)`?  (Though `Items` seems like an unintuitive name for *a single value*.)

Comment: Answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396378/c-sharp-linq-orderby-numbers-that-are-string-and-you-cannot-convert-them-to-int

Comment: Items was used as an example :) it was a value in my own language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the strings to integers while sorting. This can be done like that:

```
MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<clsItemsModel>(_clsItemsDataService.GetItems()
                                   .OrderByDescending(p => Convert.ToInt32(p.Items)));
```

But f you have to be afraid that `Items` may contain things that cannot be converted to integers, you'd rather use `int.TryParse()`:

```
MyCollection = new ObservableCollection<clsItemsModel>(_clsItemsDataService.GetItems()
                   .OrderByDescending(p => 
                   {
                       int n;
                       return int.TryParse(p.Items, out n) ? n : int.MinValue;
                   }));
```

---

**Note** that `OrderByDescending` is *not* an instance method of `ObservableCollection<T>`. It does **not** sort that instance, but returns a new `IEnumerable<T>` that represents the sorted sequence. Thatswhy I create a new `ObservableCollection<clsItemsModel>` from the sorted sequence returned by `OrderByDescending`.

---

Second note: you said you want "ascending" numbers, but use `OrderByDescending`. I copied that part, maybe you want to use `OrderBy` instead.

Comment: THIS WORKED!!! Yes that was a mistake using the OrderByDescending because i was trying to see what the combobox would do then. Forgot to change it back.