# Sorting Arraylist collection having items as Strings

Tags: c#, collections

I have an array list that comprises of elements like:
 **M1,M2,M3...M9,M10,M11** so on. 
When I sorted the elements using built in sorting feature, **M10 and M11** get placed in **2nd and 3rd position** respectively after **M1**.

Is there anyway to sort where I need **M10 and M11** to come after **M9**?

Comment: Write your custom IComparer and use it in the Sort overload.

Comment: Probably the most sane solution is not to use `Arraylist` and use something more modern (unless you really have the use case to do so) on saying that, it wont help your problem

Comment: Replace it with `List<string>` and then you can `Sort()`

Answer (score 1):

similar kind of question and some accepted solutions can be found in below link

[c# linq orderby numbers that are string (and you cannot convert them to int)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396378/c-sharp-linq-orderby-numbers-that-are-string-and-you-cannot-convert-them-to-int)

Answer (score 0):

You can use IComparable to  implement custom sorting for your class. Basicaly, IComparable allows custom sorting of objects when implemented.

Just check the following [Example](https://www.dotnetperls.com/icomparable):

```
class Employee : IComparable<Employee>
{
public int Salary { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }

public int CompareTo(Employee other)
{
    // Alphabetic sort if salary is equal. [A to Z]
    if (this.Salary == other.Salary)
    {
        return this.Name.CompareTo(other.Name);
    }
    // Default to salary sort. [High to low]
    return other.Salary.CompareTo(this.Salary);
}
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called [Natural sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order)
There is a [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NaturalSort.Extension/) package for `.Net` implementation

Then you can sort your array very easy

```
arr.OrderBy(x => x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.WithNaturalSort());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are, without any external packages:

```
     class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // Initializing your list of strings
      List<string> list = new List<string>()
      {
        "M9", "M2", "M7", "M11", "M5", "M6", "M3", "M8", "M1", "M10", "M4", "M12"
      };

      SortStringList(list);
    }

    private static void SortStringList(List<string> list)
    {
      // Bubble sort
      bool change = true;

      while (change)
      {
        change = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
          if (i + 1 < list.Count)
          {
            // here im converting the string to a number removing the first char "M"
            int currentElement = Convert.ToInt32(list[i].Remove(0, 1));
            int nextElement = Convert.ToInt32(list[i + 1].Remove(0, 1));
            // comparing two integers and swapping the strings elements
            if (currentElement > nextElement)
            {
              string tmp = list[i];
              list[i] = list[i + 1];
              list[i + 1] = tmp;
              change = true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`OrderBy` with custom `IComparer` could be useful. Try this:

```
var list = new List<string> { "M10", "M2", "M9", "M1", "M22" };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list.OrderBy(_ => _, new Comparer())));
// M1, M2, M9, M10, M22
```

Where custom `IComparer<string>` could be implemented like this:

```
class Comparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y) 
        => x.Length != y.Length ? x.Length - y.Length : string.Compare(x, y);
}
```