# Sort a list of strings which contains float numbers

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of object which contains a field Number. This field is a string that includes float numbers: 0.5, 0.2, 10.0, 2.2, 2.1, 1.1, 1.0, 2.12, 1.14.
I want this list sorted (descendent) based on this Number so I have this output: 10.0, 2.2, 2.12, 2.1, 1.14, 1.1, 1.0, 0.5, 0.2.

I have tried to do this:

`List<MyObject> sortedList = myUnsortedList.OrderyDescending(x => x.Number).ToList();`

Also, I have tried to use PadLeft like this (as this user suggested https://stackoverflow.com/a/6396523/3872144):

`int maxlen = myUnsortedList.Max(x => x.Number.Length);`

`List<MyObject> sortedList = myUnsortedList.OrderyDescending(x => x.Number.PadLeft(maxlen, '0'));`

But in both cases I got wrong results like: 2.12, 10.0, 2.2, 2.1, 1.14, 1.1, 1.0, 0.5, 0.2.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Just order by thier casted(double) value

Comment: yes, solved my issues. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question arises why you have a `string` in the first place if you store a `double`. You should parse them as soon as possible (or prevent that they are strings where you load them).

However, you can always try to parse them afterwards:

```
List<MyObject> sortedList = myUnsortedList
    .OrderyDescending(x => double.Parse(x.Number))
    .ToList();
```

If you dont know if they have all a valid format you can use `double.TryParse`. Maybe you need to pass the appropriate `CultureInfo` to `double.Parse`(for example if your current culture uses comma as decimal separator).

Comment: That's what I needed. For some reasons I cannot change de type, but it works properly with the Parse. Thank you!