# Sorting string with number in Umbraco Razor

Tags: c#, linq, razor, umbraco

In a Umbraco site I have an address in a string, so that string will contain a number, like: `Street Road 2, Street Road 14, Street Road 22b` etc.

I am sorting the list by address (among other values)

```
var apartments = Umbraco.Content(Guid.Parse("f3c9c894-16e5-491e-b39f-77bf2cb13c6f"))
.ChildrenOfType("ApartmentItem")
.Where(x => x.IsVisible()).OrderBy(x => x.Value("apartmentItemStatus")
.ToString().Replace(" ", "")).ThenBy(x => x.Name.ToString().Replace(" ", ""));
```

The expected result would be

```
Street Road 2
Street Road 14
Street Road 22b
```

But the actual result is

```
Street Road 14
Street Road 2
Street Road 22b
```

I can't figure out how to sort it correctly. I would like to avoid splitting the string, taking the number, converting to int, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort strings alphabetically while accounting for value when a string is numeric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396378/how-do-i-sort-strings-alphabetically-while-accounting-for-value-when-a-string-is)

Comment: "I would like to avoid splitting the string, taking the number, converting to int" - then you won't be sorting by numeric value. You will have to do one or more of these things.

Answer (score 0):

Using some extension methods on `String`, you can create an `IComparer<IEnumerable<string>>` for sorting `IEnumerable<string>` such that non-numeric strings sort normally, and numeric strings sort by length, then by string value. Then you can split the addresses into words, and sort using the new comparer.

```
public static class StringExt {
    static Regex wordRE = new(@"\w+", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.NonBacktracking);
    public static IEnumerable<string> Words(this string s) => s.Matches(wordRE);
    public static IEnumerable<string> Matches(this string s, Regex re) => re.Matches(s).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value);

    public static bool IsAllDigits(this string s) => s.All(ch => Char.IsDigit(ch)); // faster than Regex
}

public class WordsAndNumbersComparer : IComparer<IEnumerable<string>> {
    StringComparer cmp;

    protected WordsAndNumbersComparer(StringComparer c) => cmp = c;

    public WordsAndNumbersComparer Create(CultureInfo ci, bool ignoreCase)
        => new WordsAndNumbersComparer(StringComparer.Create(ci, ignoreCase));

    static WordsAndNumbersComparer currentCultureComparer;
    public static WordsAndNumbersComparer CurrentCulture
        => currentCultureComparer ??= new WordsAndNumbersComparer(StringComparer.CurrentCulture);

    static WordsAndNumbersComparer currentCultureIgnoreCaseComparer;
    public static WordsAndNumbersComparer CurrentCultureIgnoreCase
        => currentCultureIgnoreCaseComparer ??= new WordsAndNumbersComparer(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

    static WordsAndNumbersComparer invariantCultureComparer;
    public static WordsAndNumbersComparer InvariantCulture
        => invariantCultureComparer ??= new WordsAndNumbersComparer(StringComparer.InvariantCulture);

    static WordsAndNumbersComparer invariantCultureIgnoreCaseComparer;
    public static WordsAndNumbersComparer InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
        => invariantCultureIgnoreCaseComparer ??= new WordsAndNumbersComparer(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    static WordsAndNumbersComparer ordinalComparer;
    public static WordsAndNumbersComparer Ordinal
        => ordinalComparer ??= new WordsAndNumbersComparer(StringComparer.Ordinal);

    static WordsAndNumbersComparer ordinalIgnoreCaseComparer;
    public static WordsAndNumbersComparer OrdinalIgnoreCase
        => ordinalIgnoreCaseComparer ??= new WordsAndNumbersComparer(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public int Compare(IEnumerable<string> firstWords, IEnumerable<string> secondWords) {
        return firstWords.Zip(secondWords)
                     .Select(fst => {
                         if (fst.First.IsAllDigits() && fst.Second.IsAllDigits()) {
                             var lenCmp = fst.First.Length.CompareTo(fst.Second.Length);
                             if (lenCmp != 0)
                                 return lenCmp;
                         }
                         return cmp.Compare(fst.First, fst.Second);
                     })
                     .FirstOrDefault(c => c != 0, 0);
    }
}
```

With these defined, you can use them like so:

```
var ans = src.OrderBy(s => s.Words(), WordsAndNumbersComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

which sorts your example street addresses as expected.

NOTE: Using the .Net 7 `Regex` enhancements around `ReadOnlySpan<char>`, you could probably write a version of `WordsAndNumbersComparer` that takes a `string` and uses the enhancements internally to reduce object (string) creation for the comparison. But because `OrderBy` caches keys, pulling the invariant key computation out may be more efficient than constantly slicing the address when sorting.