# Split string to digits and alphabets in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like this

`12,3 m`  and i need 2 sub strings one decimal value and one unit like `12,3` and `m`

`12.3` will return `12.3` and `m`

`123,4 c` will return `123,4` and `c`

The decimal separators can be . or ,

So how can i get it in C# without iterating through every characters like below

```
char c;

for (int i = 0; i < Word.Length; i++)
{
  c = Word[i];

  if (Char.IsDigit(c))
    string1 += c;
  else
    string2 += c;
}
```

string input is not really needed to be formatted like this it can be like A12,3 m or ABC3.45 or 4.5 DEF etc. So string Split is not stable always

Comment: Did u try Regex.Split() to split your value based on , or  . or whitespace depending upon how u wish to split

Comment: are you splitting on the decimal character or on the whitespace between the number and the alphabetical character?

Comment: Yes can do a split and apply Regx , but looking for a single line solution

Comment: it will give you a single line solution right? You dont need to iterate

Comment: ABC3.45 = ABC and 3.45 OR A and B and C and 3.45 ?

Comment: Furthermore ABC3.45 m = ABCm and 3.45 ? OR ABC and m and 3.45 or A and B and C and m and 3.45 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to separate character and number part from string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968049/how-to-separate-character-and-number-part-from-string)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are trying to split based on the whitespace character:

```
input = "12.3 c";
string[] stringArray = string.Split(input, ' ');
```

You can then do a `float.Parse` operation on the first element of the array. The decimal separator used by `float.Parse` would depend on your culture and if the wrong one is chosen you could get a `FormatException`.

You can also choose the decimal separator programatically through the below:

```
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."; // or ","
```

Comment: string input is not really needed to be formatted like this it can be like A12,3 m or ABC3.45 or 4.5 DEF etc. So string Split is not stable always

Comment: @JibinMathew then put that information in your question, because it changes entirely the question and what the solutions are. Do you only want the numbers?

Comment: why the downvote? it answered the original question.

Comment: @JibinMathew you should make an EDIT to your original question more clear, e.g. EDIT: blah blah

Answer (score 0):

Checking your provided examples `{ "12,3 m", "A12,3 m", "ABC3.45", "4.5 DEF"}` it seems that the string position can not only change but there can be 2 strings and one decimal in your inputstrings.

This solution will show you how to extract these data with only one regex and no manual string split. I will incorporate the CultureInfo from user1666620:

```
string[] inputStrings = new string[] { "12,3 m", "A12,3 m", "ABC3.45", "4.5 DEF"};
Regex splitterRx = new Regex("([a-zA-Z]*)\\s*([\\d\\.,]+)\\s*([a-zA-Z]*)");
List<Tuple<string, decimal, string>> results = new List<Tuple<string, decimal, string>>();
foreach (var str in inputStrings)
{ 
    var splitterM = splitterRx.Match(str);
    if (splitterM.Success)
    {
        results.Add(new Tuple<string, decimal, string>(
            splitterM.Groups[1].Value,
            decimal.Parse(
                splitterM.Groups[2].Value.Replace(".", System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator).Replace(
                    ",", System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator)
            ),
            splitterM.Groups[3].Value
        ));
    }
}
```

This will find all possible combinations of a present/not present string in pre/post position, so be sure to check the individual strings or apply any combining logik unto them.

Also it doesn't only check for the presence of a single space between the decimal and the strings but for the presence of any number of whitespaces. If you want to limit it to definately only 0 or 1 space instead replace the Regex with this:

```
Regex splitterRx = new Regex("([a-zA-Z]*)[ ]{0,1}([\\d\\.,]+)[ ]{0,1}([a-zA-Z]*)");
```