# Splitting text and integers into array/list

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to find a way to split a string by its letters and numbers but I've had luck.

An example:
I have a string `"AAAA000343BBB343"`

I am either needing to split it into 2 values `"AAAA000343"` and `"BBB343"` or into 4 `"AAAA"` `"000343"` `"BBB"` `"343"`

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Regex is your friend here.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share you work and we can help from there.. You don't just want a solution but some help, right??

Comment: can you explain more about the spliting? how do you decide where to split?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968049/how-to-separate-character-and-number-part-from-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `RegEx` approach to split your string into 4 values

```
string input = "AAAA000343BBB343";
string[] result = Regex.Matches(input, @"[a-zA-Z]+|\d+")
                       .Cast<Match>()
                       .Select(x => x.Value)
                       .ToArray(); //"AAAA" "000343" "BBB" "343"
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly thanks :) I really need to research more on Regular Expressions

Answer (score 2):

So you can use [regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)

For

> "AAAA000343" and "BBB343"

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z]+\d+");
var result = regex
               .Matches("AAAA000343BBB343")
               .Cast<Match>()
               .Select(x => x.Value);

// result outputs: "AAAA000343" and "BBB343"
```

For

> 4 "AAAA" "000343" "BBB" "343"

See @fubo answer

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var numAlpha = new Regex("(?<Alpha>[a-zA-Z]*)(?<Numeric>[0-9]*)");
var match = numAlpha.Match("codename123");

var Character = match.Groups["Alpha"].Value;
var Integer = match.Groups["Numeric"].Value;
```

Comment: This will only grab the first instance of letters and numbers, not both. You should try it with the provided data, instead of `codename123`.  Good use of named captures, though.